# When to use what statistical test: 1 qualitative 2 quanitiative variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, data-mining

I hope this isn't too simple of a question, but I am having difficultly choosing which test to use in my analysis.

As for background, I am studing the migration patterns of different species of birds and relating that information to the average temperature in the area to see if the migration patterns have been effected by increasing temperatures.

My basis for mapping out the migration pattern is through observed sigtings of the bird. So, if there are more sightings in a certain area, more of the population is in that area.

Currently, my data is split into three data sets, each for a different time period (1955-1975, 1975-1995, and 1995-2015). Each dat set includes all of the regions in which a particular species is found for each month of the year, the number of sightings in each region per month, and the average temperature in each region and month.

I have used t-tests just to confirm that the average temperature in each region and month is increasing as you progress through each twenty year time period; however, I'm struggling to determine if that would be an approprate test to determine if the migration pattern is changing due to the increasing temperatures.

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.